Error Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations' shows up only after deployed
Had the nested error pop up in my springboot application only after deployed on Heroku. Worked as intended when running on localhost. Database connection is fine and all the env variables are set correctly.
2024-07-31T04:43:55.735688+00:00 app[web.1]: 2024-07-31T04:43:55.735Z  INFO 2 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.client                : MongoClient with metadata {"driver": {"name": "mongo-java-driver|sync|spring-boot", "version": "4.11.1"}, "os": {"type": "Linux", "name": "Linux", "architecture": "amd64", "version": "5.15.0-1063-aws"}, "platform": "Java/Azul Systems, Inc./17.0.12+7-LTS"} created with settings MongoClientSettings{readPreference=primary, writeConcern=WriteConcern{w=null, wTimeout=null ms, journal=null}, retryWrites=true, retryReads=true, readConcern=ReadConcern{level=null}, credential=MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='servingarlesbiz', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}, transportSettings=null, streamFactoryFactory=null, commandListeners=[], codecRegistry=ProvidersCodecRegistry{codecProviders=[ValueCodecProvider{}, BsonValueCodecProvider{}, DBRefCodecProvider{}, DBObjectCodecProvider{}, DocumentCodecProvider{}, CollectionCodecProvider{}, IterableCodecProvider{}, MapCodecProvider{}, GeoJsonCodecProvider{}, GridFSFileCodecProvider{}, Jsr310CodecProvider{}, JsonObjectCodecProvider{}, BsonCodecProvider{}, EnumCodecProvider{}, com.mongodb.client.model.mql.ExpressionCodecProvider@3bc4ef12, com.mongodb.Jep395RecordCodecProvider@50448409, com.mongodb.KotlinCodecProvider@5634a861]}, loggerSettings=LoggerSettings{maxDocumentLength=1000}, clusterSettings={hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], srvHost=cluster0.9ixeu8a.mongodb.net, srvServiceName=mongodb, mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=REPLICA_SET, requiredReplicaSetName='atlas-fi4tgy-shard-0', serverSelector='null', clusterListeners='[]', serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', localThreshold='15 ms'}, socketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=0, receiveBufferSize=0, proxySettings=ProxySettings{host=null, port=null, username=null, password=null}}, heartbeatSocketSettings=SocketSettings{connectTimeoutMS=10000, readTimeoutMS=10000, receiveBufferSize=0, proxySettings=ProxySettings{host=null, port=null, username=null, password=null}}, connectionPoolSettings=ConnectionPoolSettings{maxSize=100, minSize=0, maxWaitTimeMS=120000, maxConnectionLifeTimeMS=0, maxConnectionIdleTimeMS=0, maintenanceInitialDelayMS=0, maintenanceFrequencyMS=60000, connectionPoolListeners=[], maxConnecting=2}, serverSettings=ServerSettings{heartbeatFrequencyMS=10000, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS=500, serverListeners='[]', serverMonitorListeners='[]'}, sslSettings=SslSettings{enabled=true, invalidHostNameAllowed=false, context=null}, applicationName='null', compressorList=[], uuidRepresentation=JAVA_LEGACY, serverApi=null, autoEncryptionSettings=null, dnsClient=null, inetAddressResolver=null, contextProvider=null}

2024-07-31T04:43:55.736246+00:00 app[web.1]: 2024-07-31T04:43:55.736Z  INFO 2 --- [u8a.mongodb.net] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server ac-fjrxlmv-shard-00-00.9ixeu8a.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster

2024-07-31T04:43:55.739170+00:00 app[web.1]: 2024-07-31T04:43:55.738Z  INFO 2 --- [u8a.mongodb.net] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server ac-fjrxlmv-shard-00-02.9ixeu8a.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster

2024-07-31T04:43:55.744072+00:00 app[web.1]: 2024-07-31T04:43:55.743Z ERROR 2 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'jwtAuthenticationFilter' defined in URL [jar:nested:/app/target/MyTry-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/!BOOT-INF/classes/!/com/charliemartinezdominguez/MyTry/config/JwtAuthenticationFilter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'applicationConfig' defined in URL [jar:nested:/app/target/MyTry-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar/!BOOT-INF/classes/!/com/charliemartinezdominguez/MyTry/config/ApplicationConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.charliemartinezdominguez.MyTry.user.UserRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on ApplicationConfig: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'

At a loss here on why it only happens when deployed. Here are the files that are mentioned in the error message. They are all within the src package with jwtfilter and appconfig in their own package and userrepo in another.
JwtAuthenticationFilter
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private final JwtService jwtService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request, @Nonnull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userName;

        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        userName = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        if (userName != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);
            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                        null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

                authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

ApplicationConfig
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Autowired
    private final UserRepository repository;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> repository.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found"));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}

UserRepository
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, ObjectId> {
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
}

